# Exception handling broken in Delphi XE8 Android

Tags: android, delphi, exception, delphi-xe8

I have an application which has been working on Android for over a year.

Suddenly it has stopped working altogether.

It appears that the try..except..end mechanism has failed completely.

To verify, create a form with one TLabel and one TButton.

Add the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Text := 'What???';
  Try
    StrToInt('xxx');
  Except
    Label1.Text := 'Exception';
  End;
end;
```

I can run this and correctly debug it on my Sony phone but the exception does not get called and the application just closes.

Comment: Seems hard to believe that nothing changed but your program now behaves differently

Comment: Yes it does. That's why I produced a standalone verifiable example. I suspect some update in the Android runtime possibly but have tried factory resetting my development phone, which does not seem to have helped.

Comment: On which version of Android seems the exception handling broken? Delphi XE8 does not officially support Android 6. I once developed app which runs correctly on Android 5, but had exception handling issues on Marshmallow. No problems with Delphi Seattle though.

Comment: @Erwin, both devices are now on 6.0.1 - I do have access to Berlin and Seattle Delphi Pro licenses but the mobile pack only for XE8. This seems like a possible cause, particularly if you have had exception handling issues as well.

Comment: @Erwin please repeat your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi XE8 does not [officially support](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) Android 6. I once developed app which runs correctly on Android 5, but had exception handling issues on Marshmallow. No problems with Delphi Seattle though. Glad to hear upgrading to [Delphi 10 Berlin](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Berlin 10.1 solved the problem immediately.

@Erwin if you care to propose that as an answer instead of a comment I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: Pen, @Erwin won't get notifications inside answers. It must be in comments.